# Nodemailer 3LO OAuth give GaxiosError: unauthorized_client

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api, nodemailer

In emailTransporter.js my code like below.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const path = require('path');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')});

const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    process.env.CLIENT_ID, // ClientID
    process.env.CLIENT_SECRET, // Client Secret
    "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" // Redirect URL
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
});
const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken();

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: process.env.USER_EMAIL, 
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken: accessToken
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

module.exports = transporter;
```

In auth.js I use emailTransporter exports from emailTransporter.js to send some email options. But node give me error like this:

D:\nodejs\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:129
throw new common_1.GaxiosError(`Request failed with status code ${translatedResponse.status}`, opts, translatedResponse);
^

GaxiosError: unauthorized_client
at Gaxios._request (D:\nodejs\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:129:23)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (D:\nodejs\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:174:21)
at async OAuth2Client.refreshAccessTokenAsync (D:\nodejs\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:198:19)
at async OAuth2Client.getAccessTokenAsync (D:\nodejs\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:227:23) {
response: {
config: {
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
data: 'refresh_token=1%2F%2F04PvTQnD4_86nCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrTdRMaV9mdIMhyEhFeJeKGSvqYnbgkCw-18aF7ZFmRgpWoWiQM3EXozwMiXzvfYwmAwc&client_id=543495663437-d59lg6u1a77o9a2uinf83idb0md991l9.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=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&grant_type=refresh_token',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/7.11.0',
'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/16.13.2 auth/7.11.0',
Accept: 'application/json'
},
paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
body: 'refresh_token=1%2F%2F04PvTQnD4_86nCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrTdRMaV9mdIMhyEhFeJeKGSvqYnbgkCw-18aF7ZFmRgpWoWiQM3EXozwMiXzvfYwmAwc&client_id=543495663437-d59lg6u1a77o9a2uinf83idb0md991l9.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=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&grant_type=refresh_token',
validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
responseType: 'json'
},
data: { error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'Unauthorized' },
headers: {
'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
connection: 'close',
'content-encoding': 'gzip',
'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
date: 'Wed, 19 Jan 2022 03:47:31 GMT',
expires: 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
pragma: 'no-cache',
server: 'scaffolding on HTTPServer2',
'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
'x-xss-protection': '0'
},
status: 401,
statusText: 'Unauthorized',
request: { responseURL: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' }
},
config: {
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
data: 'refresh_token=1%2F%2F04PvTQnD4_86nCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrTdRMaV9mdIMhyEhFeJeKGSvqYnbgkCw-18aF7ZFmRgpWoWiQM3EXozwMiXzvfYwmAwc&client_id=543495663437-d59lg6u1a77o9a2uinf83idb0md991l9.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=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&grant_type=refresh_token',    headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/7.11.0',
'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/16.13.2 auth/7.11.0',
Accept: 'application/json'
},
paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
body: 'refresh_token=1%2F%2F04PvTQnD4_86nCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrTdRMaV9mdIMhyEhFeJeKGSvqYnbgkCw-18aF7ZFmRgpWoWiQM3EXozwMiXzvfYwmAwc&client_id=543495663437-d59lg6u1a77o9a2uinf83idb0md991l9.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=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&grant_type=refresh_token',    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
responseType: 'json'
},
code: '401'
}

Comment: Where line does your error occur in your showing script?

Comment: Your redirect uri cant be oauth playground your code isnt running on play ground.   Remove the refresh token and try the authorization again let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, I have to choose option Use your own credentials at top right side. Fill in the cliendId and clientSecret and it already worked.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// I was able to go around this issue by using the clientId and secret 
// directly in the file. I realized it wasn't 
// picking up the id and secret values from the .env file.
// My test only works with Node.js at the moment. not sure if it works for  
// other program/language.

import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

import { google } from "googleapis";

const CLIENT_ID = "insert your client id from goodle cloud console";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "insert your client secret from goodle cloud console";
const REDIRECT_URI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground";
const REFRESH_TOKEN = "insert your refresh token from oauth playground";

const OAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URI
);

OAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });

export default async function sendVerificationEmail(email, name, url) {
  try {
    const accessToken = await OAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: "sender@gmail.com",
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
    });
    const mailOptions = {
      from: "Support  <sender@gmail.com>",
      to: email,
      subject: "Facebook email verification",
      text: "Facebook email verification",
      html: `<div style="max-width:700px;margin-bottom:1rem;display:flex;align-items:center;gap:10px;font-family:Roboto;font-weight:600;color:#3b5998"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dmhcnhtng/image/upload/v1645134414/logo_cs1si5.png" alt="" style="width:30px"><span>Action requise : Activate your facebook account</span></div><div style="padding:1rem 0;border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5;border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;color:#141823;font-size:17px;font-family:Roboto"><span>Hello ${name}</span><div style="padding:20px 0"><span style="padding:1.5rem 0">You recently created an account on Facebook. To complete your registration, please confirm your account.</span></div><a href=${url} style="width:200px;padding:10px 15px;background:#4c649b;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-weight:600">Confirm your account</a><br><div style="padding-top:20px"><span style="margin:1.5rem 0;color:#898f9c">Facebook allows you to stay in touch with all your friends, once refistered on facebook,you can share photos,organize events and much more.</span></div></div>`,
    };
    const result = transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return err;
      return res;
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.